# importing simpy in python - unnamed module error

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, simpy

I am trying to import `simpy` package in python, however I get the unnamed module error. I am on a Mac OSX and have `anaconda` installed. I installed it using `pip install simpy` command. These outputs could also be helpful:

```
$ which python
//anaconda/bin/python

$ pip list
simpy (3.0.10)

$ conda list
simpy                     3.0.10                    <pip>
```

(If relevant, I am using PyCharm as IDE)

Comment: which simpy? //anaconda/bin/python?

Comment: OnurA, edit your question and provide the full trace-back you receive when you enter `import simpy` in your terminal or IDE; with the trace-back your question will be more clear and asnwerable.

Comment: @DanielLee: what do you mean by which simpy? if you want me to type in which simpy, it doesn't give any output. But I also tried it with numpy (which works fine with import), it doesn't give any output either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error could be caused by your project configuration in pycharm pointing to another python interpreter, maybe python3 or a virtualenv?

Check it by going through your project settings.

Make sure you are using the same interpreter in PyCharm as the one where you installed your module.

Comment: Yes you are right, in the project settings > project interpreter, python 2.7 is selected, which is installed in /usr/bin/python. What would be the correct path for anaconda?

Comment: the one you mentioned in your question should work.( output of which python)